# Retrieve current folder on custom command on gnome-terminal

Tags: terminal, gnome, zsh, gnome-terminal, fish

I'm using fish for some days upon Ubuntu gnome but I don't know if that's possible to keep the feature "open the terminal in a specific folder". Inside Files app, I right click inside a folder a press `Open in terminal`.

I've overided in my terminal the custom command used when the terminal is open :

- From top menu: `Edit` -> `Profile Preference`.
- Then `command tab`, check the `Run custom command instead of my shell` and set `fish` as custom command.

[image: custom fish command]

When I open a terminal, I always end up in my home dir, even when I open my terminal from another directory

I've tried to setup a custom shell script to retrieve params `/home/me/runFish.sh $@` but it's not working

Comment: To get fish to open a specified folder on startup, use the `-C` flag with the `cd` command, e.g. for the home folder `fish -C 'cd $HOME'`. I’m not a Linux user, so I have no idea what magic variable will pass the selected folder to the command (that “open here” thing works out of the box with fish on the Mac), but you might be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: Yes I don't know how to access to the folder passed as a param, as this is not documented on gnome-terminal